# ScrollView not scrolling Vertically at all even by adding SetBarEnabled

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Using following code but I am not able to Scroll `WebView` vertically. Horizontally it works fine but Vertically impossible. I have tried everything, Have no idea what is wrong.....

```
public class OAuthentication extends Activity
{
    private WebView myWebView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.oauth_layout);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        try {
        String authUrl = String.format(Constants.OAUTH_URL, 
                                Constants.API_KEY,
                                URLEncoder.encode("r_fullprofile rw_nus r_emailaddress r_network w_messages", "UTF-8"),
                                UUID.randomUUID().hashCode(),
                                Constants.REDIRECT_URI_OAUTH);

            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            myWebView.loadUrl(authUrl);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

In **oauth_layout.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_header"
        />

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />   

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What happens if you Change to `android:orientation="horizontal"`

Comment: Maybe this helps you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819896/scrolling-in-android-with-webview-working-perfectly)

Comment: @Oli its a "Top Bar", RelativeLayout I can't change it to horizontal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it, Looks like I had to add a ScrollView.. This is strange tho.

Answer (score 0):

Set layout_height of RelativeLayout to match_parent.